# How to truncate the request URI in Smarty to get just the first chunk?

Tags: php, smarty, smarty3

In Smarty 3 and in my special scenario, this

`{$smarty.server.REQUEST_URI}`

returns a URI with 4 chunks, like "/category/vendor/articlenum/articlename".

How can I modify this string using Smarty to get just "/category" or "/category/"?

Comment: Try to use parse_url() function of php. for help regarding this function check url: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just found another solution that I'll post soon.

Comment: Please put so that others also get help through that.

Comment: Don't struggle to do strings processing in Smarty. It's not its purpose in life. Do the processing in PHP, assign the result to a Smarty variable, use it in templates as-is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found one possible solution by first removing the leading slash with substr. Then, I use regex_replace to delete the tail, starting with the first remaining slash.

`{assign var=truncUri value=$smarty.server.REQUEST_URI|substr:1|regex_replace:"/\/(.*)/"}`

This results in the string "category". After this step, I use the result in the template:
`/{$truncUri}/`